# Скрипт изменения ширины элемента с шагом, в зависимости от ширины viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть

```
<div id="smiley-box" class="smiley-box"></div>
```

Нужно чтобы при ширине от 767px до 991px, его ширина изменялась от 15.25% до 16.5% с шагом в 0.25%. Как можно реализовать это через JS, чтобы увеличение происходило равномерно?

Comment: А через css не пойдёт?

Comment: @Artem Platonov, "при ширине от 767px до 991px" - ширине чего? Экрана? Родителя?

Comment: @eccs0103, в css transition-duration  указывается время, не "шаг по размеру"...

Comment: @ksa а я что-нибудь об `transition-duration` говорил?

Comment: @eccs0103, тогда скажи про что ты не говорил но думал... :)

Comment: @ksa [@media](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.php) правило, который меняет стили в зависимости от каких-либо условий. К примеру от размера `viewport`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141594/discussion-between-eccs0103-and-ksa).